# Is there a good way to get new token if old one is not available for installed GitHub app?

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, github-app, github-oauth

Currently I am trying to build a Github Pages site that will act as an editor for the data in a users repository. At the moment when the user initially uses the site, they are directed to install the Github app, and when this happens they are redirected back to the site, with the code in the url. The site then sends this code to a server with [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/prose/gatekeeper) on it, the token is returned, and is stored in the users cookies. According to [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-user-access-token-for-a-github-app):

> By default, the user access token expires after 8 hours. You can use a refresh token to regenerate a user access token. For more information, see "Refreshing user access tokens."

I am fine with the token expiring every 8 hours, and I understand your supposed to use the refresh token to refresh it, but the issue is that I do not understand what is supposed to happen if the application loses these tokens. Does the user have to uninstall and reinstall the app if they move to another browser?

My guess is that maybe you could send the user through the Oauth flow and they'll get a refreshed token for the app, but this brings up the issue that you can't tell if the user has installed the app. As a result, it appears the only way to do this is to send the user through the Oauth flow, use the token from that to check if the app is installed, and then if its not send them through the app install process, which seems ridiculous.

So, my question is, **if the user authentication token is not available for an installed app, what is the intended way for the application to get one?**

If anyone can find any projects that have this implemented as an example that would be great.

Additionally, the reason I'm having the user install the app instead of just authenticating with it is that it appears to be the only way the app can access their private repositories.

**EDIT**: I found this information [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/36463) and

I have attempted with both of these API's and neither has returned private repos:

https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos

```
const apiUrl = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos';
const params = {type: 'private'};

fetch(`${apiUrl}?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `token ${accessToken}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:USERNAME

```
const apiUrl = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:${username}+is:private`;

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `token ${accessToken}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.items);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Aside - it seems like you should be able to list private repositories given the right OAuth token using the right search query against the `/search/repositories` endpoint or the `/user/repos` endpoint as well ([source](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24382)); have you tried either of those options? It might be beneficial for you, and potentially preclude the need for much of this hoop-jumping.

Comment: On-topic to the question at hand: where are you storing these OAuth tokens? Do your users have some sort of expectation that their authentication information will magically propagate to different browsers on their machine? If the application doesn't have the tokens for the user, what is the resistance to sending them through the OAuth flow again, as you would with a new user (who would also not have tokens stored for their account)?

Comment: Sending them through the OAuth flow again is what I would like to do, but I would prefer to avoid sending them through two different flows one after the other. Maybe this isn't possible, but that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an authenticated or installed GithubApp I just used an OauthApp, which can access private repos and gets around the whole issue.